# In QGIS, how to convert northing and easting from a CSV file into longitude and latitude so it fits with the rest of my data?

Tags: qgis, convert, csv

I'm adding a CSV file into my map where all the other data comes from shapefiles. I tried messing with the coordinate system, but I can't get the data to show up as datapoints on my map.

Comment: Correctly setting the spatial reference should do the job. Please [Edit] the question to specify the SR in which the data was collected, and what exact steps you tried.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: Does the CSV data show at all, in say a new project without any other data?  Can you perhaps show the first few lines of the CSV.

Comment: Could you please post the header and 2-3 records of you CSV file?